# Does spark .sql() use optimisation techniques such as predicate/filter push down and selection/projection push down?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, optimization, apache-spark-sql

Using a statement such as

```
val sql = s"""Select <column names> from <source> where <filter>"""
spark.sql(sql)
```

Then later running queries such as:

```
val filteredDF = df.filter(filterExp)
or
val selectDF = df.select(col1, col2, col3)
```

I'm wondering:

1. Whether the optimisations of predicate and projection push down are applied in a `.sql()` command?
2. Whether, if later running `.filter()` or `.select()` operations, would these be pushed down to the read level?

From running some checks with `.explain()`, it seems that in (2.) these pushed down operations do not happen. Why?

Comment: Using .sql() or the Scala API, both will be using the catalyst optimizer, normally they should do the same actions, can you provide a reproducible example so we can understand why the (2.) is not working.

Comment: Ultimately dataframe api and sql api both translate to similar intermediate language (IL) or intermediate representation (IR) for optimization by the Tungsten compiler. I don't think there would be separate pipelines to optimize them differently. To test this, write a block of code which will be optimized together as a whole. I think it will be optimized in similar way but I could be wrong.

Comment: This is a good article : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/catalyst-tungsten-apache-sparks-speeding-engine-deepak-rajak/

Answer (score 1):

In short yes, they do.  Per Abdennacer's response sql("") parses the sql into the very same instructions (plan + expression trees) as using the api does.  Further filters or select projections will do the same.

There are limits to what can be pushed down however, in particular only literals are pushed down with support for a variety of primitive comparisons.  The [sources](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/filters.scala) interface shows what is possible at a source level.

The actual supported operations are dependent on the underlying source.

The limitation on literals can show itself in a couple of ways I've experienced / worked around:

- if an expression cannot be folded into a literal (converting a string date to an int would be possible) (this hit [frameless](https://github.com/typelevel/frameless/issues/343))
- if the logic is asymmetric (you calculate a field in a projection then filter against that calculated value - spark cannot know if the operation is reversable) (this hit [Quality](https://github.com/sparkutils/quality/issues/9))

The first is something internal to Spark expressions or custom expressions, the latter is easy to trigger in normal user code:

```sql
selects as_uuid(lower, higher) as context from underlying_table
where context = '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000'
```

The [as_uuid](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/sqlfunctions/#as_uuid) function takes two longs and converts to a string uuid, so the above is filtering on a string which doesn't actually exist in the underlying_table.  Solving that required writing a custom plan which runs early enough to convert the filter into filters on the underlying lower and higher yielding pushdown.

Also possible is a difference between terminology when using different datasources/engines, under Databricks photon/delta you won't see PredicatePushdown in the plan but something like datafilter (I forget the actual term).

To get a reason why your query doesn't push down predicates you'll need to specify the sql used and source type.

It's worth noting that even if a pushdown is possible it doesn't automatically provide speed bumps - e.g. if there are no statistics collected for parquet / delta for your field you'll end up scanning anyway.

(also worth noting on projection side projection filters are also used to reduce what is loaded from a file and are source dependent as to what that means, although for columnar formats the unused data can simply be skipped in the reads).